# Recover Joomla webstite with database

Tags: joomla

somehow (i don't know why...) my website created with joomla doesn't work anymore. The only thing that i have is the website's files and the database. Do someone know a way to recover the website? Thank in advance!

**EDIT**
Basically if you go to www.safetyprivacy.it you will find a page with http error 500. But if i go to the administrator panel (in the login page there isn't any problem) what i see is this:

[image: admin panel]

In the image there's the admin panel (italian language) but it isn't styled and you cannot navigate it

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Files and database is what powers a Joomla website so you're not missing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fatal error on your Joomla website somewhere. Open the `configuration.php` file and change `$error_reporting` from "none" to "maximum", and you should see the error causing this.

I think most likely your website is hacked, or you have installed an extension lately that has a bug and that caused all this mess.